# Module 'spacy.util' has no attribute 'filter_spans' in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, nlp, jupyter-notebook, spacy

I have spacy version 2.2.4 (also tried with 2.1.4).

```
import spacy
...
result = spacy.util.filter_spans(spans)
```

**ERROR: module 'spacy.util' has no attribute 'filter_spans'**

I am running jupyter notebook from a virual environment and installed spacy inside it too.
The documentation says filter spans shoud be included: https://spacy.io/api/top-level#util.filter_spans

Context: Trying to reproduce code from https://towardsdatascience.com/auto-generated-knowledge-graphs-92ca99a81121

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define the function by yourself and use it:

```
def filter_spans(spans):
    # Filter a sequence of spans so they don't contain overlaps
    # For spaCy 2.1.4+: this function is available as spacy.util.filter_spans()
    get_sort_key = lambda span: (span.end - span.start, -span.start)
    sorted_spans = sorted(spans, key=get_sort_key, reverse=True)
    result = []
    seen_tokens = set()
    for span in sorted_spans:
        # Check for end - 1 here because boundaries are inclusive
        if span.start not in seen_tokens and span.end - 1 not in seen_tokens:
            result.append(span)
        seen_tokens.update(range(span.start, span.end))
    result = sorted(result, key=lambda span: span.start)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

The next code snippet worked for me with spacy 2.2.4 version installed:

```
from spacy.util import filter_spans
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')

doc = nlp("This is a sentence.")
spans = [doc[0:2]]
filter_spans(spans)
```

Output

```
[This is]
```

Comment: Hi IMB, I receive the following message: cannot import name 'filter_spans' from 'spacy.util' .

Comment: Can you try !pip list | grep spacy

Comment: I use windows with Jupyter Notebook, if I run "python -m spcy info" I get:
============================== Info about spaCy ==============================

spaCy version    2.2.4
Location         C:\Users\Graphineer\anaconda3\envs\nlp\lib\site-packages\spacy
Platform         Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
Python version   3.7.7
Models

Comment: Maybe spacy didn't compile properly. Try to reinstall spacy with conda.

Comment: nothing worked - but I found the function here: https://spacy.io/usage/examples