# spacy lemmatization of nouns and noun chunks

Tags: nlp, spacy, lemmatization

I am trying to create a corpus of documents which consists of lemmatized nouns and noun-chunks. I am using this code:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

def lemmatizer(doc, allowed_postags=['NOUN']):                                                     
    doc = [token.lemma_ for token in doc if token.pos_ in allowed_postags]
    doc = u' '.join(doc)
    return nlp.make_doc(doc)


nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('merge_noun_chunks'), after='ner')
nlp.add_pipe(lemmatizer, name='lemm', after='merge_noun_chunks')

doc_list = []                                                                                      
for doc in data:                                                                                    
    pr = nlp(doc)
    doc_list.append(pr)
```

The sentence `'the euro area has advanced a long way as a monetary union'` after identifiying noun-chunks `['the euro area', 'advanced', 'long', 'way', 'a monetary union']` and lemmatization gets to: `['euro', 'area', 'way', 'monetary', 'union']`.
Is there a way to combine the words of the identified noun-chunks to get an output like this: `['the euro area','way', 'a monetary union']` or `['the_euro_area','way', 'a_monetary_union']`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your problem is about lemmatization.
This method works for your example.

```
# merge noun phrase and entities
def merge_noun_phrase(doc):
    spans = list(doc.ents) + list(doc.noun_chunks)
    spans = spacy.util.filter_spans(spans)
    
    with doc.retokenize() as retokenizer:
        for span in spans:
            retokenizer.merge(span)
    return doc

sentence = "the euro area has advanced a long way as a monetary union"
doc = nlp(sentence)
doc2 = merge_noun_phrase(doc)
for token in doc2:
    print(token)
    #['the euro area', 'way', 'a monetary union']
```

I have to note that I'm using spacy2.3.5, maybe `spacy.util.filter_spans` is deprecated in the newest version. This answer would help you. :)

[Module 'spacy.util' has no attribute 'filter_spans'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259356/module-spacy-util-has-no-attribute-filter-spans-in-jupyter-notebook)

And, if you still try to lemmatize noun chunks, you can do it as following:

```
doc = nlp("the euro area has advanced a long way as a monetary union")
for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
    print(chunk.lemma_)
    #['the euro area', 'a monetary union']
```

According to the answer in [What is the lemma for 'two pets'](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/4028), "looking at the lemma on the span level is probably not very useful and it makes more sense to work on the token level."